# how to load a list<t> from a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a gridview and i am trying to load up the list with a column from the grid view and i m getting a null reference exception

i have tried this

```
    public static List<string> LoadStringList()
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

        if (contactDataGridView.RowCount != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < contactDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringList.Add((string)contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

        }
        return stringList;
    }
```

and i tried this

```
    public static List<string> LoadStringList()
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

        if (frmPRG299.mainForm.contactDataGridView.RowCount != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <frmPRG299.mainForm.contactDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringList.Add((string)frmPRG299.mainForm.contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

        }
        return stringList;
    }
```

farther explanation

i have two forms frmMain and frmSub where the gridview is in frmMain and a combobox in frmSub i need to call the  function `LoadStringList()` to populate the Combobox

Comment: Mostly other users will redirect you here: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186#4660186)

Comment: try to check for null or empty before adding it into stringList. try using using as instead of cast.

Comment: @Viju i need to cast because i need convert the object type to string type

Comment: Remove the static word from the function and try referencing the actual objects.  Or, change your call to `public static List<string> LoadStringList(DataGridView dgv)` and pass the existing control as a reference.

Comment: You can always do

var stringData = contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value as string;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringData ))
{
  add stringData to stringList
}

Comment: @LarsTech i have two forms one with a datagridview and one with a combobox and i need the list to populate the combobox and i need to use the function to

Comment: @LarsTech  why remove the static keyword ?

Comment: If you don't know what "static" does, why did you put it in your function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
stringList.Add((string)contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
chaange the code to
stringList.Add(contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["YOUR COLUMN NAME"].Value+"");

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'frmPRG299.contactDataGridView

Comment: Remove static keyword from the function

Answer (score 0):

Use a method that allows you to reference an object (a Control in this case), and pass to the method a reference to that object.
Without a hard-coded object reference, your method is more flexible.

Here I'm passing to the method a `DataGridView` control reference and a cell number from which to extract the current value.

Since the `Cell.Value` could be `null`, you have to verify it before attempting to read it and/or transforming it to the required type.

```
List<string> MyList = LoadStringList(this.dataGridView1, 2);


public List<string> LoadStringList(DataGridView dgv, int cell)
{
    if ((dgv == null) || (dgv.RowCount == 0)) return null;

    List<string> result = dgv.Rows.Cast< DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(r => { return r.Cells[cell].Value != null 
                            ? r.Cells[cell].Value.ToString() 
                            : default; })
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

If a more generic input type is needed:

```
try
{ 
    List<int> MyList = LoadList<int>(this.dataGridView1, 2).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle the exception/Update the UI/Prompt the User
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

```
public IEnumerable<T> LoadList<T>(DataGridView dgv, int cell)
{
    if ((dgv == null) || (dgv.RowCount == 0)) return null;

    IEnumerable<T> result = null;

    try
    {
        result = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                         .Select(r => { return r.Cells[cell].Value != null
                                   ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(r.Cells[cell].Value, typeof(T))
                                   : default;
                            })
                         .ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //Manage the exception as required
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public List<string> LoadStringList(DataGridView contactDataGridView)
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

        if (contactDataGridView.RowCount != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < contactDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var stringData = contactDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value as string;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringData))
                {
                    stringList.Add(stringData);
                }
            }

        }
        return stringList;
    }
```

Comment: will not work because object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'frmPRG299.contactDataGridView'

Comment: why remove the static keyword ? could you explain

Comment: if contactDataGridView was accessible in the instance then static would not work , But if you are passing the DataGridView to the method it can be static.